# How call method from service container in config in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have some variables in twig-templates, so think use global scope for it.

```
config.yml
twig:
 globals:
  varA: "@wf.autoload.getA"
  varB: "@wf.autoload.getB"
```

In **service yml** I have:

```
services.yml
 wf.autoload:
  class: Scope\WfBundle\WfAutoloadService
  arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

**WfAutoloadService** class have public function for getting variables

```
    class WfAutloadService {
    ...
    public function getA(){
    return ...;
    }

    public function getB(){
    return ...
    }
    ...
    }
```

My idea doesn't work. Method of `@=service(wf.autoload).getA()` also doesn't work.

Is it possible? Or it bad idea and bad practice?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I must use another services, f.e wf.autoload.getA and call method in it?

Comment: it is better to create twig extension to define this functions (getA, getB)

Comment: Do you want to access the twig global variables in controller?

Comment: @DOZ and then use them in templates? I would use only Variable as such as I set them for render.

Comment: @AlokPatel, nope. in twig-templates. For constructions such as {{ foreach A in varA }}. Now I do it so {{ foreach A in varA.getA }}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If getA() and getB() returns object, you can use a factory when configuring your service:

```
services:
    wf.autoload:
        class: Scope\WfBundle\WfAutoloadService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    wf.autoload.getA:
        class:   A
        factory: ["@wf.autoload", getA]
```

And set the global twig:

```
twig:
 globals:
  varA: "@wf.autoload.getA"
```

Comment: That's what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I you want to use this functions in many twig templates you can create a twig extension

For example :

```
class MyExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
            return array(
                'getA' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getA', array('is_safe' => array('html')))
            );
    }

    public function getA() // you can if you want pass parameters
    {
       //your code

       return ...
    }
}
```

Declare it as service :

```
myextensions.twig_extension:
      class: Project\YourBundle\Twig\MyExtensions
      public: false
      tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

And call it in yours twig template :

```
{{ getA() }}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it something another that I want.